# Pivot selections

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying the hide the selections in my pivot with below code but it is hiding only first selection. rest is as it is.

Any help in mitigating it will be helpful.

```
Sub pivotselection()

Sheets("DailyHK").Select
Range("I16").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("type").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NS").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CA").Orientation = xlHidden
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Hw")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
Range("H34").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
Sheets("MonthlyFS").Select
Range("P13").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Otype").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("D4").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think it's pretty much impossible to find the exact issue without seeing the workbook. Still, here are some lines to get you moving in the right direction. Note that you don't need any of those 'select' lines. All they do is confuse your code and make it harder to understand and debug.

```
' first of all define a pivot table object that we can work with
dim pt as PivotTable

'set the object to hold the first pivot table
set pt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DailyHK").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

'do stuff with pt (note the . at the beginning of each line in between "with" and "end with"
With pt
    .PivotFields("type").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("NS").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("CA").Orientation = xlHidden
End With

'set the object to hold the second pivot table
set pt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyFS").PivotTables("PivotTable4")

With pt
    .PivotFields("Otype").Orientation = xlHidden
End With

'finally kill the object
set pt = Nothing
```

Good luck! If you're still stuck, make sure to upload the workbook somewhere (without your actual data) or provide a screenshot at least.

Comment: Thank you burtelli for your review, However issue is with regards to     .PivotFields("NS").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("CA").Orientation = xlHidden  which is not getting applied on  pivot.

Comment: Ok, what happens? Do you get an error or is it that nothing happens at all? Make sure the data column names (NS and CA) are correct and the fields are actually visible in the first place. I believe you will run into an error if they aren't. If you need further help you'll need to provide the file.

Comment: Nothing happens, pivot applies for .PivotFields("type").Orientation = xlHidden condition only.

Comment: Well, I can't figure out the the problem w/o a file. Try debugging your macro step by step as described here. [link](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)
Good luck!